# link database to php script to c# on a server

Tags: unity-game-engine, phpmyadmin, directadmin

I need some help! i just cant figure it out. i have made a game (WebGL) added a database script using unity UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post and i have a PHP file. i uploaded the game build and the PHP file to a server.  in the root directory of the domain, i want to use. i have my index.html (game) its folders and a SQL connect folder with the PHP script inside. I have made a database in PHPMyAdmin and put the connections in the PHP script. well, i can't get it to work. i really need some help!! please! on localhost it works fine but i cant get it to work online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out it was the CORS header that was missing once i added that everything showed